# Kendo Scheduler: Set DataSource and Resource from one returned Object with two array properties

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Basically I'm returning an object with two array properties inside it.
One is for the Event Datasource and one is for the Attendees Resources.

The initial server-side function should be called from the main event dataSource of the scheduler.

The attendees "Resources" is constructed from the event "dataSource", but with added information at the back-end. Which means, Attendees resources is fully dependent on whatever data is going to be returned by the Event dataSource. So when the event dataSource changes, the attendees resource would also be refreshed from the UI.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm using the Attendees resources for grouping.

Comment: some source code and the json structure with dummy data would help explain better.